# Div with nested block-level elements loses styling in IE7

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer-7

I'm building a site using the 960gs and some styling of my own. My navigation menu uses this code:

```
<nav class="push_1">
                        <div class="grid_2 alpha"><span>About</span><a href="#" title="About"></a></div>
                    <div class="grid_2"><span>Services</span><a href="#" title="Services"></a></div>
                    <div class="grid_2"><span>Projects</span><a href="#" title="Projects"></a></div>
                    <div class="grid_2"><span>Client Stories</span><a href="#" title="Client Stories"></a></div>
                    <div class="grid_2"><span>Contact</span><a href="#" title="Contact"></a></div>
            </nav>
```

And this CSS:

```
.container_12 .grid_2 {width:140px; display:inline; float: left; position: relative; margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px;}
nav{background:#666; z-index:2; font-family:tahoma, helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight:bold; letter-spacing:1px; overflow:hidden}
nav div{position:relative; background:url(http://placehold.it/140x250/z03); height:250px; display:inline-block }
.interior nav div{height:50px}
nav div span{display:block; background-color:#111; color:#fff; padding:.3em 0; text-align:center; border-bottom: 2px solid #777;opacity:.9}
nav div a{display:block; position:absolute; top:0; height:100%; width:100%; z-index:5}
```

Which works fine in Firefox, but fails miserably in IE7, where only the text within the `<span>` elements appears and all other styling is lost. I've run into this same issue when trying to use `<li>` items instead of `divs` as well. Curiously, the same code shows no problems in IE7 when the height of `nav div` is set to 50px, as it is on pages with `class="interior` set on the body. The HTML5 shim is in effect on this page. I've tried searching through various known IE7 bugs, but couldn't find one that quite matched the problem I'm having. If anyone has any suggestions, I'd be much obliged.

Comment: Have you set `nav { display: block; }`? Can you find out what happens in IE8?

Comment: @BoltClock setting `nav {display:block;}` didn't do anything for me. That's one of the settings that the HTML5 shim is supposed to take care of automatically in Explorer. I believe I had the same problem on IE8 as well, but the machine I'm working on right now only has IE7. I'll have to check when I go to work tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IE8, I could replicate the issue.  What I found was that is was the  tags that were confusing it.  If I changed those to  and added "nav" as a class on those divs and then changed "nav" to ".nav" in the CSS, IE seems to be happy.  You can see it in action here in this jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/Vz85f/

If you still want the  tags in for other reasons, it appears that you can wrap the HTML in the fiddle with  before and  afterwards and it will still display appropriately in IE - just don't use nav in the CSS rules.  I'm unsure why - just reporting what I found with experimentation.

Comment: This worked! But your mentioning that IE was confused by the `<nav>` tag had me scratching my head, too. Turns out that Google's link to the HTML5 Shim removes the http protocol in the src URL, which IE doesn't like it all. Adding it back in fixed the problem right away. Still, thank you for the help. :)